# Prof. Theodore Shifrin wrote "a differentiable function on an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with nowhere zero drivative has a differentiable inverse"

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse-function

Prof. Theodore Shifrin wrote "a differentiable function on an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with nowhere zero drivative has a differentiable inverse" on p.251 in his "Multivariable Mathematics".

Is the following argument ok?

> If $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and $f^{\prime}(x)\ne 0$ on $I$, then by the intermediate value theorem, $f^{\prime}(x) > 0$ on $I$ or $f^{\prime}(x) < 0$ on $I$. So $f$ is strictly increasing on $I$ or $f$ is strictly decreasing on $I$. So $f$ has a differentiable inverse.

Comment: IVT assumes continuity, and you don't know if your $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you for your comment. If $f(x)$ is differentiable on $I$, then $IVT$ for $f^{\prime}(x)$ holds even if $f^{\prime}(x)$ is not continuous. I found this theorem in my analysis book written by Teiji Takagi.

Comment: +1, makes sense now

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for Darboux's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux's_theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much for your information.